# Xcode 6 Linker error Google Analytics Services Unity 3d

Tags: xcode, google-analytics, unity-game-engine, linker

i've got a problem at the build process in xcode 6.
I'm getting this linker error and i don't know what to do.

```html
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/username/Documents/Development/Unity/1_-_Unity_2D/AppName/AppName_iOS/Libraries"'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm confused because the Libraries folder is included in the Library Search Paths:

```html
"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries"
```

Also 'libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a' is included in "Link Binary With Libraries".

Please help me.

Regards
Dennis

Edit:
Removing and adding again in "Link Binary With Libraries" was the soution for this problem.
I tried it multiple times, then it worked. Strange but I'm okay with that.

Good luck!